# SetText () method does not work if the element its associated with an onItemSelected () element of a Spinner

Tags: java, android

I have an activty which has an EditText and a Spinner, in which when selecting an element of the Spinner, the selected element must be displayed in the EditText. Until then everything goes well. But if I want to assign a value to that EditText, outside of the onItemSelected method proper to the Spinner, it simply does not show the string I assigned it with the setText method.

```
deps = new ArrayList<>();
cargarDeps();
deps.add("");


adapterSPDep = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.lista_sp, deps);
spDep.setAdapter(adapterSPDep);
spDep.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {

            auxDep = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            txtDep.setText(auxDep);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // txtDep.setText(auxDep);

        }
    });
```

that code its in the onCreate of my activity, my method "cargaDeps()" is linked to a webservice which obtains all the departments that exists, which I save in the ArrayList "deps". In the onItemSelected () method of the Spinner is where I assign what my EditText is selected. But when I call this method:

```
public void rellenar(String[] campos) {


    txtNum.setText(campos[4]);
    txtFecha.setText(campos[1]);
    txtHora.setText(campos[2]);
    txtDes.setText(campos[3]);
    txtTipo.setText(campos[4]);


    txtDep.setText(auxDep);


    txtReporta.setText(campos[6]);
    txtAtiende.setText(campos[7]);


}
```

in txtDep.setText (auxDep); no value is assigned.

Comment: add source code

Comment: where do you call rellenar method and what is the value of auxDep that you pass in?

Comment: The activity receives data from another activity and I receive it in a Bundle:
Bundle b = this.getIntent (). GetExtras ();
        if (b! = null) {
 if (b.getStringArray("datos") != null) { datos = b.getStringArray("datos");rellenar(datos);
  }
}
auxDep is a static global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make a global String value and assign the value you want to get from the spinner to the String value.